# PHP value from input with onclick

Tags: php, html

There are two fields from the calendar, the initial and the current date of the input, where the date is selected. I just can not figure out how to pull the value after the selection with onclick
I tried by id or name through POST but it still doesn’t work with the usual input, everything is fine with a POST method

```
<form method="post">
   <h3>Click on the date entry field to call the calendar.:</h3> 
   <p>
      from the <input name="d1" type="text" 
            value="day month Year" 
            onfocus="this.select();_Calendar.lcs(this)" 
            onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;this.select();_Calendar.lcs(this)"  
            data-yearfrom="-80"
            data-yearto="5">yearto="5" />

      to the <input name="d2" type="text" 
            value="day month Year" 
            onfocus="this.select();_Calendar.lcs(this)" 
            onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;this.select();_Calendar.lcs(this)" 
            data-yearto="5">yearto="5" />

      <input  type="submit" name="select1"  form="myform" value="data from bd" />
  </p> 
</form>
```

Comment: Your text input elements will NOT appear in any POST request because they do not have a name attribute. Give them a name and try again

Comment: the first `input` is missing its `name` attribute, so it won't get posted to the server. The browser won't submit a field unless it has an attribute e.g. `name="d1"`

Comment: You're also not closing your `<form`-tag (missing the `>`) You also have an unmatched `</p>`.

Comment: Instead of responding to any of the comments, you edited the code in your question by adding some very oddly placed spaces and line breaks?

Comment: everything changed as it should still not work

Comment: Well, you're still not closing the opening `<form ...`-tag. Also, currently, you've only showed us the HTML. Where's the code that tries to get these values when they are posted? You know, the code you're actually having issues with?

Comment: Also, your submit button has: `form="myform"` while your form doesn't have any name or id. Please read up on how to properly use these HTML elements, what attributes they have and what those attributes does.

Comment: You are right, I did not have an id form. I corrected and got a satisfying result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed all the syntax errors:

```
<form method="post" id="myform">
    <h3>Click on the date entry field to call the calendar.:</h3>
    <p>
        from the <input name="d1" id="d1" type="text"
                        value="day month Year"
                        onfocus="this.select();_Calendar.lcs(this)"
                        onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;this.select();_Calendar.lcs(this)"
                        data-yearfrom="-80"
                        data-yearto="5"/>

        to the <input name="d2" id="d2" type="text"
                      value="day month Year"
                      onfocus="this.select();_Calendar.lcs(this)"
                      onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;this.select();_Calendar.lcs(this)"
                      data-yearto="5"/>

        <input type="submit" name="select1" form="myform" value="data from bd"/>

    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Even if this might solve the issue, a good answer includes an explanation of what you've changed and why. Just posting a chunk of code without any explanation (or even a comment) isn't very constructive.

Comment: what explanations? I wrote that I did not take the value from the input with the onclick

Comment: @Capricorn - Who was that comment for and what does it comment on?